# Get the size of data returned by SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where in we need to limit the number of records returned by SQL query depending on the size of the data. There are multiple select statement in the stored procedure. Is there a way to know the total size of data that the query may return. I know that we have Include Client Statistics on option in management studio but i want to know whether we can get this information during run time.

TIA,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit broad, do I understand the down-votes!

However, I would recommend using "count" to count the number of rows being returned.  You will need to modify the queries / procedures to add this logic, performing the query with the count, check for the number of rows returned, then decide if you want to continue or not.

```
select count(*) from library_books where loaned_out='Y';

count(*)
--------
     563
```

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion is you calculate an average size for each row.  That also mean calculate average size of each field.

Then you limit result to

```
RowAvgSize * Count(*) < YourSizeLimit
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM table
LIMIT ( YourSizeLimit / RowAvgSize ) ::integer
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange requirement... without knowing the basis for the need, it's difficult to give a recommendation.  It seems like the best way to limit results is to use `SELECT TOP` to return a fixed number of rows or percent.

If you really need to do some calculations, you could output your results to a temporary table and then do a calculation to determine how many rows you want to return.  Something like:

```
select *
into #temp
from MyBigQueryHere

declare @Rows as integer
set @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT

--insert calculation to modify value of @Rows here
set @Rows = sqrt(@Rows) --example

select top(@Rows) *
from #temp
```

Comment: Thanks for that.. However the requirement is not to limit the number of rows but the size of data. The data will be exported to excel and will be used by downstream system. The problem is downstream system wont accept any file of size greater than 10 MB.

Comment: You could find out the size of the data by multiplying the size of each record times the row count.  But even then... that will not tell you the size of that data when inserted into an excel spreadsheet.  You could find out how many rows of your data will fit into a spreadsheet of size less than 10MB and then just limit your results to a max of that number of rows.

Comment: There are multiple recordset we are returning from the query and columns returned in each set is different. so it is not possible to know the rowsize.